# how can i redirect http to https in ubuntu from virtualhost?

Tags: apache, https, virtualhost

I am not an expert in server configuration, I need to redirect http to https using VirtualHost

what I already try is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName myservername
    Redirect /  https://myservername
<VirtualHost>
```

This is work perfectly means if anyone use `http://myservername` then they redirect to `https://myservername`

but the problem is when someone use `http://myservername:3030` then it doesn't work, I need to redirect `http://myservername:3030` to `https://myservername:3030` also.

Comment: I really doubt you can't have both an http server and an https server listening on the same port. That has absolutely nothing to do with AngularJS, BTW.

Comment: yes, @JB Nizet you are absolutely right that's why `http://myservername:3030` did not give any response but I need to redirect it on `https://myservername:3030`

Comment: I fail to follow your reasoning: I'm absolutely right in saying that it can't be done, because you want to redirect from 3030 to the same port, but nevertheless, even though you agree that it can't be be done, you still want to do it?

Comment: Okay, @JB Nizet, I got your point, is there any possible way? for this